# Testing java webservice using SOAP UI

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

I am testing a java webservice using SOAP UI version 5.0. I have deployed the EAR of my code on WAS 8 using RAD as the IDE for development and deployment.

My code works perfectly fine when I test it on RAD but doesnot work on SOAP UI.

I am getting a DataAccessException

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server
version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or
later.
```

I dont get this exception when i run i test it via JUnit on RAD. When i researched on the error i found out that it occurs if an outdated version of sqljdbc driver is used but i am using the recent version 4 of sqljdbc so that reason is also eliminated.

Somehow the connection to the database seems to be not happening when i run it via soap ui but i am puzzled to see that the same thing works fine in RAD and doesnot work in SOAP UI.

The database it is trying to hit is a SQL server database and i am using RAD 8.5.1 with WAS 8.

Any pointers on this would be very much useful.

Thanks.

Comment: where are you getting this error?

Comment: i am getting this error in the RAD console when i fire a soap request on my wsdl endpoint which is hosted on my local server.

Comment: on the soap ui response field i only get  'Message: Error accessing database'

Comment: you said it works "perfectly fine" in RAD but not in SOAP UI. It appears that the issue is in the server. Perhaps it is not using the driver you expect, or perhaps the driver does not actually support your SQL server version.

Comment: So let me get this correct...are you saying that i need to do some additional configurations related to the driver for my service to work in SOAP UI?

Comment: What is the best way to debug this issue apart from looking at the console logs?

Comment: show the junit code and the soap ui request. if the clients are causing the issue, you need to investigate what is different between the junit request and the soap ui request (and responses). Soap ui is not making a jdbc connection, junit might be doing anything. If the server is responding differently, it is interpretting the requests differently. You may need to check logs to determine this.